# Multiple statement is passed in IF condition using OR, how to find which statement is true?

Tags: java, if-statement

If multiple conditions are passed in `if` statement with `OR(||)`, how to find which one is true of that given statements in java?

```
if(a==0 || b==0 || c==0)
{
    //How to find which statement passes access inside IF condition
}
```

Comment: 1. Print the values of `a` `b` & `c` inside if block 2. Step through debugger and add a watch to variables.

Comment: Short version: You can't - if you need to know then check them individually

Comment: Easy enough, you just check each of them separately. `if (a == 0) { ...} else if (b == 0) { ... } else if (c == 0) { ... }`.

Comment: `System.out.println(a==0)` as well as the others

Comment: You can always check them with a debugger. However, if it is important to know which statement to be true at a specific moment you probably need to rethink your strategy (eg. do not pass all conditions into the same if statement, but it is hard to know the best approach). If you want to log it you can just add a DEBUG log entry of all the statement (`logger.debug("a: {}, b: {}, c: {}",  a==0, b==0, c==0)`).

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the result of the conditions and then check it inside.

```
boolean atrue = a == 0;
boolean btrue = b == 0;
boolean ctrue = c == 0;
if(atrue || btrue || ctrue)
{
   if (atrue) {
     ..
   }
   if (btrue) {
     ..
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to.

Comment: You should if it is a more complicated condition, e.g. if there is some method called to do some calculations. If it is just a==0 then you don't need to store the result - this is true.